# Update one Access Table from a Query

Tags: ms-access

Maybe this is more complicated than it needs to be, or maybe it's simpler. Either way, it has been driving me nuts and I would really appreciate any help.

I've tried searching google and stack overflow, as well as a Safari Book on Access with no success, but maybe I just cannot clearly define what I want enough to find it.

I am creating a database in Access. Thus far I have 2 tables:
Area Information
Zone Information

Area Information has a table that has a "Zone" Column with a 2 letter abbreviation for which zone it belongs to. (Example: AA, GB, DT)
Zone Information has a table that has "Abbreviation" as well as "Number of Areas"

What I would like (and here is where I may be completely off base...I thought I could do it in mySQL before, but I'm really quite new to Access):

I would like to be able to add new rows to Zone whenever I want, which will automatically populate with "Number of Areas" in that zone.

I think it needs to

```
SELECT Count([Area Information].Zone) AS CountOfZone, [Area Information].Zone
FROM [Area Information]
GROUP BY [Area Information].Zone
```

And from there,

```
HAVING ((([Area Information].Zone)=[Zone Information].Abbreviation));
```

Too bad this one doesn't work.

Lastly, it would need to then update the proper row in that column.

If anyone can help me clear this up, I would appreciate it. I've been trying everything I can think of, and my google-fu has gone soft on me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may need to use a "Join" but I am just so confused about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the central concepts in relational database design is *Normalization*, which is a fancy word for saying "don't 'write down' the same piece of information in more than one place".

You *think* that you want to store the "Number of Areas" for each Zone in the [Zone Information] table, but you already have that information "written down" in the [Area Information] table. You just need a handy way to pull it out.

As you guessed, an aggregation (GROUP BY) query is the answer, and one like this...

```
SELECT [Area Information].Zone, Count(*) AS [Number of Areas]
FROM [Area Information]
GROUP BY [Area Information].Zone;
```

...will produce results like this:

```
Zone    Number of Areas
----    ---------------
AB      3
BC      3
NS      1
ON      2
```

If you save that query in Access as "AreaCountsByZone" then you can use that *query* just like a *table* in other queries you build, such as a query that shows the Area counts *without actually storing the counts in the [Zone Information] table itself*...

```
SELECT [Zone Information].Abbreviation, [Zone Information].[Zone Name], 
    AreaCountsByZone.[Number of Areas]
FROM AreaCountsByZone INNER JOIN [Zone Information] 
    ON AreaCountsByZone.Zone = [Zone Information].Abbreviation;
```

...which returns...

```
Abbreviation    Zone Name   Number of Areas
------------    ---------   ---------------
AB              Zone AB     3
BC              Zone BC     3
NS              Zone NS     1
ON              Zone ON     2
```

As you get more comfortable with SQL you may find it more convenient to skip the intermediate "saved query" and just do the whole thing in one shot:

```
SELECT [Zone Information].Abbreviation, [Zone Information].[Zone Name], 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM [Area Information]
     WHERE [Area Information].Zone = [Zone Information].Abbreviation
    ) AS [Number of Areas]
FROM [Zone Information];
```

...which produces exactly the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had been thinking a few times "why am I trying to structure it like this?" and the though that maybe I didn't since it was a query came to mind (somehow I lost this in translation from my simple MySQL workings and using access). my only problem may be this: each zone has a name as well as the abbreviation. Is there a way (other than storing name and Abbreviation in the Area Information table) to link each abbreviation to a name? Thanks again!

Comment: @TeddJohnson Notice in my answer that I *do* have a [Zone Information] table with [Abbreviation] and [Zone Name] columns. The [Zone Name] belongs in that table because again, *Normalization* suggests that you only "write down" the Zone's name in one place (the one record in the [Zone Information] table) instead of repeating it many times in the [Area Information] table. This is different from the "Number of Areas" case, where you have to associate Areas with Zones in the [Area Information] table anyway, so storing the COUNT() in the [Zone Information] table would be redundant.

Comment: @TeddJohnson Also, bear in mind that there can be some particular circumstances where a certain amount of *Denormalization* might be necessary. For example, if your [Area Information] table was **huge** and you found that things were bogging down because of re-calculating the COUNT() values repeatedly, then perhaps that might cause you to consider actually storing the Area counts in the Zones table. However, Access does not offer some of the advanced features (such as `TRIGGER`s) to help manage cases like this, so think carefully before taking such action.